# Controlling Digital to Analog Converter using trackbar control in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ascii, trackbar

I've created an application where I need to control a Digital to Analogue Converter (DAC) using horizontal trackbar control in VB.Net.

I've used checkbox (appearance: button) to control relays to switch them on and off and I'm sending Ascii values from program to do it.

Is it possible to do the same for trackbar? I am confused because unlike checkbox control which can be given two discrete values I'll need continuous values for trackbar. I'm new to VB.Net, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set value range of your trackbar using its **Minimum** and **Maximum** properties. (e.g. 0 to 255)
2. Trackbar also has **Value** property. On every manipulation with trackbar slider, this property is updated. So just read this numeric value (similarly as you read Checked property from checkboxes) which is guaranteed to be between minimum and maximum you set.

Comment: Please let me know whether this helped you.